# Create list of string with variable name in jmeter - groovy

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter

I have an issue that I am dealing with, I created a framework of 100 tests that should run nightly all together. 
all tests have the same step of creating list of string.
I want to each test give a new string name (not to change manually since I will duplicate it many more times).
I created a function that will generate random names, and want to use it as the list name.
when I declare it I got exception 
random is a string that got randomized name generated to it, each test.
in this case random was = 100545GKFN.
I want to create list with the name of 100545GKFN is it possible?
What shall happened if in Jmeter I will create in each thread group the same list name? can Jmeter handle many lists with the same name (each in different thread group)? for example 1000000 lists with the name my_list? each in different thread group, and to add to each string according to each tests?

```
List<String> vars.get("random") = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that I didn't understand your question entirely...
Nevertheless, can you use some different data structure, like this:

```
    Map<String, List<String>> domain = new HashMap<>();
    String name;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_LISTS; i++) {
        name = getRandomName(); //you provided this method
        domain.put(name, new ArrayList<>());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The declaration statement seems odd in that vars.get("random") returns some object which is null or has been instantiated.  Declaring the return value as a List<> is the problem.  Try

```
List<String> myRandomList = new ArrayList<String>();
// ...
myRandomList = someFunctionThatReturnsARandomList();
// ...
vars.set("random") = myRandomList;  // Assuming vars is a key-value map type
```

or cast the vars.get() return value as a List

```
List<String> myRandomList = (List<String>) vars.get("random");
```

If you want to access it directly, you could try statements like

```
((List<String>) vars.get("random")).add(newRandomValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by creating a random id, and put it in variable called ran_id.
and use this command each time to create a list

```
props.put("list_${ran_id}", my_list);
```